# get_terms orderby most popular post views wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I added custom field `post_views_count` to every post to track post view count, it works. But also I need to show all taxonomy categories orderby that most popular post view count, here is my code, but seems it is not working at all:

```
$args = array(                                      
    'hide_empty' => true,                                       
    'fields' => 'all',                                      
    'hierarchical' => true,                 
    'child_of' => 0,                                        
    'get' => '',                                        
    'name__like' => '',                                     
    'pad_counts' => false,                                      
    'taxonomy' => 'video-category',                                     
    'cache_domain' => 'core',
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
);
$terms = get_terms('video-category', $args);
```

Comment: are you getting all posts but order not working?

Comment: I have updated my code, pls check it, I am trying to dispaly all category names orderby most popular viewed post @Gopal S Rathore

Comment: it will not work... check possible arguments over here ... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms